# change style for a specific chapter

Tags: chapters, report, minitoc

how to make that introduction in the middle,bigger ? like this

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, blindtext}
\newcommand{\changefont}{%
    \fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont
}
\usepackage{minitoc}



\begin{document}


\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Introduction Générale}
\addstarredchapter{Introduction Générale}

\chapter{title number one }

\chapter*{Bibliographie}
\addstarredchapter{Bibliographie}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I e.g. can't find the text you show in the picutre in the MWE. However, have you tried to set the text inside a `\MakeUppercase` command?

Comment: @Steradiant I have changed now it is clear
it's in `\chapter*{Introduction Générale} \addstarredchapter{Introduction Générale}`

Comment: @Steradiant how we can i do with ? i don't know this command !

Comment: `\chapter*{\MakeUppercase{Introduction Générale}}`

Comment: @Steradiant great that work  and to centering in the middle `\chapter*{\textbf{\MakeUppercase{Introduction}}}`

Comment: If you want to change it globally for all `\chapter` titles, use `\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
{\centering\normalfont\Large}
{\thechapter}
{.5em}
{\MakeUppercase}
[\vspace{.5ex}]` in the preamble (the \MakeUppercase is not necessary in this case anymore).

Comment: @Steradiant  the problem i want just in one chapter that is `\chapter*{\textbf{\MakeUppercase{Introduction}}}` because the style of our establishment is like that

Comment: Then use `\chapter*{\centerline{\MakeUppercase{Introduction Générale}}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
\chapter*{\centerline{\MakeUppercase{Introduction Générale}}}
```

if you only want it centered and upper case for this one specific chapter heading.

[image]

Comment: great that works thank you very much !